# Is the union of two CFLs minus their intersection a CFL?

Tags: context-free

I've seen the classical proofs of CFLs are not closed under intersection or complement, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around this. Intuitively, I think that this would be not a CFL but I can't think of any counterexamples.

Comment: symmetric difference.

Answer (score 2):

If one of the languages is $\Sigma^*$, what is the union minus the intersection?

Hope that gives you ideas.